# Replace space in a Java string by backslashe

Tags: java, string

how can i replace spaces char in a java string by backslashes ?

I tried this :

```
String text = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
text = text.replace(" ","\\");
System.out.println(text2);
```

but have a look on the result in eclipse debug variables :

```
text 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
text2 \\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\10
```

but in my logs result is different :

```
07-18 14:56:31.049: I/System.out(9177): \1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9\10
```

I want to use it with a smb command to allow space in a directory file name. This command works when i set it manually in my code. The result should be like this :

```
source : smb://192.168.0.254/Disque dur/
text = text.replace(" ","\040");
result : smb://192.168.0.254/Disque\040dur/
```

But when i am using the replace() method there is double backslashes...

```
result : smb://192.168.0.254/Disque\\040dur/

07-18 15:15:10.439: E/Home(9538): jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name cannot be found.
```

Thanks for help

Comment: So do you want to replace all spaces with `\ ` , `\\ ` or  `\040`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
String text = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
text = text.replace(" ","\\\\");
System.out.println(text2);
```

A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler.
'**\\**'    Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

You can read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: why does this work? can you explain why the question's code is acting like this?

Comment: Backslash is an escape character in Java.  Therefore if you want to represent a backslash in a Java literal you have to use double-backslash. "\\" in java equals \

Answer (score 2):

Backslash needs to be escaped in Java. See this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html):

> \\   Insert a **backslash** character in the text.

`\\` - Represents `\`.
`\\\\` - Represents `\\`.

Don't let the console fools you, what you are seeing there is actually a single `\`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove space like this

```
    String mysz = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
String mysz2 = mysz.replaceAll("\\s","");
System.out.println(""+mysz2);
```

Answer (score -3):

In Java, the string "\" represents a single backslash. If you want double backslashes, you have to write "\\".

Comment: doesnt answer his question at all

Comment: Really? There are several other answers here that say EXACTLY the same thing. So they are all wrong and deserve downvoting? -.-

Comment: Yes. the answer is wrong. An old thread, but as it took me longer to figure out than I am proud of: you missed the escaping. Doubling your backslashes between the quotes would lead to a correct answer...